# Windows 7 installation using Windows PE

Tags: 64-bit, x86, tftp, windows-pe

Is it possible to install Windows 7 (**64-bit**) using Windows PE (**32-bit**)?

I am following the guide available [here](http://blog.ryantadams.com/2008/02/01/how-to-boot-from-the-network-pxe-boot-with-tftp-and-windows-pe/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible, you need a 64-bit WinPE to install Windows 64-bit.

[From Microsoft Technet:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(WS.10).aspx)

> To install a 64-bit version of Windows you must use a 64-bit version of Windows PE. Likewise, to install a 32-bit version of Windows, you must use a 32-bit version of Windows PE.

Comment: Well... It's an old answer, but a worong one... Someone might stumble upon this, so I'll show why It's clearly wrong.

1. I know from first hand experience, since I actually made an All-In-One USB stick with 32-bit PE that had ALL 32-bit and ALL 64-bit versions of Windows 7 available as install-options.

2. Just check out this link to see SOME of the ways this can be done:
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-x86-x64-all-one-windows-7-iso/

Comment: @svin83 It was accurate at the time, an dI'm not convinced it not accurate now. If you have newer info, please feel free to post it as an actual answer.  But realize the question was "Can I install 64-bit using the 32-bit PE?" not "Can I make a single disk that install both Windows 32 and 64-bit?". So, if you do choose to provide an official answer, please include direct info showing that the 32-bit PE can now be used to install 64-bit Windows.

Comment: You will se how to use 32-bit PE to install both 32 and 64 bit Windows versions in the article I linked...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Windows 7 using a USB drive, there's a MUCH easier method:
[How To Create Bootable Windows 7 USB To Install Windows 7 From USB Flash Drive (Using Windows 7 DVD/USB Tool)](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-bootable-windows-7-usb-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive-using-windows-7-dvdusb-tool/)

Comment: my flash drive died while formatting so I can't install via USB installing from LAN is the only option..